# How arrays are accessed in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

If I say `$array['whatever']`, does PHP create a loop and check first one, the second one, the third one and..... OR `whatever` has an address in that array and it gets that value directly without iteration?

Thanks

Comment: no. it doesn't loop. your accessing it directly when you state array and the key.

Comment: Thanks Jason Joslin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the key you are referring, PHP will just point you directly to that key's value.

```
['whatever' => 'value']
```

You'll get 'value'